# 301 Redirections in a bundled react project that does not require Javascript, using firebase hosting

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, webpack, firebase-hosting

I'm currently building a URL shortener and am using React for its frontend. It is where my domain (let's say `example.com`) is linked to using Firebase Hosting.

I'm in a bit of a struggle trying to figure out the redirection part of the service, as I want this redirection to be "HTTP native"; it should not require JS to redirect, just a plain 301 redirection.

Shortened URLs look like this: `example.com/go/:linkId`.

When a user clicks on a shortened link, My server should get the request, find out what URL is linked to the shortened URL's id, and redirect to the original.

Since I don't want to involve JS, I tried to use the `redirects` setting in `firebase.json`. At first, it looked promising just to use:

```
"redirects": [
  {
    "source": "/go/:linkId",
    "destination": "<SERVER_URL>/go/:linkId"
  }
]
```

Two issues with this approach:

1. It won't work on localhost, as (AFAIK) `firebase.json` isn't being taken into consideration when running Webpack dev server.
2. Anyway, there is a different server URL for development and production environments. I don't want to hard-code the URL since it won't let me separate between them.

I was thinking about redirecting to a `go.js` file or something that will live in the dist folder with `index.html`, but It won't be resolved a node.js file.

If you have any idea how to solve this, I'd be glad to hear.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Redirects will work locally when you use the Firebase CLI, i.e. by running `firebase serve`. If you need to preprocess your source to get the final distribution, you do that locally, and then call `firebase serve` on the output of that preprocessing step.

Comment: While it does solve the issue of `firebase.json` being ignored, it does bring up another issue: Now hot reload doesn't work, and I am required to rebuild my project. That actually makes it even harder to develop within...

Comment: If you run `firebase serve` on the output of the preprocessor, it should hot reload changes.

Comment: What do you mean? Is this something I should configure in Webpack?

Comment: Nope. When you run webpack it takes your source folder and generates an output/dist folder. The latter is the one that you want to use as the source of Firebase Hosting and the Firebase CLI, both of which read that location from the `source` property in the `firebase.json` file.

Comment: I understand that, but when I edit my project files, webpack dev server does not rebuild them, and hot reload for *code* won't work.